# Resource Id Mismatch in Android Development

Tags: android, resources, menu

I have created a menu for my activity by writing layout and inflating it in my activity.
When i written `onOptionItemSelected` The Rid recieved from the event listener and that i have from `R.id.menu` are different eventhough i clicked on the correct menu item. It is one digit lesser than actual. so my click function is not working?

Comment: do a clean and restart your app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are 2 different ID.

The id that you use to inflate the menu is R.menu.*

But the id that you use to uniquely identify your menu is R.id.*

See here for sample:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/MenuInflateFromXml.html